# Is there any way to know transaction has completed?

Tags: ef-core-2.1

`System.Transactions.Transaction` class has `TransactionCompleted` event to which I can subscribe.

Is it possible to schedule a continuation after `IDbContextTransaction.Commit` is called?

Sure, I may call code explicitly after committing a transaction, but I have an overloaded version of `SaveChanges` where I want to detect externally started transaction and add some actions to run after it was committed.